# how to update multiple columns while comparing them between rows in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table say

table 1

### id     |   rel_id

123    |   456

789    |   321

so id column from table 1 = id from table 2 and will have catgy 180

rel_id column from table 1 = id from table 2 and will have catgy 181

```
        table 2
```

### id  |  catgy   |  spl_1    |  spl_2    | spl_3   | spl 4

123 | 180       | 6       | 0 |         0 |        7

456   | 181     | 7       | 0        | 0       |  0

789   | 180     | 8       | 9        | 9        | 0

321   | 181     | 9       | 0        | 0       |  0

so i want to comapre spl_2, spl_3, spl_4 for id 123 with spl_1 for id 456 and if same then update id 123 spl's with null(in this case update spl_4 with null)

Thanks

Comment: So you want to NULL columns if they are the same?

Comment: hi, i have edited the question. please check and answer if you can

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a standard `CASE` expression for it:

```
Update  YourTable
Set     SPCLTY_2 = Case When SPCLTY_2 = SPCLTY_1 Then Null Else SPCLTY_2 End,
        SPCLTY_3 = Case When SPCLTY_3 = SPCLTY_1 Then Null Else SPCLTY_3 End,
        SPCLTY_4 = Case When SPCLTY_4 = SPCLTY_1 Then Null Else SPCLTY_4 End,
        SPCLTY_5 = Case When SPCLTY_5 = SPCLTY_1 Then Null Else SPCLTY_5 End
```

Comment: hi, i have edited the question. please check and answer if you can

Answer (score 0):

When you need to update values in one table based on values from another table (or the same table, or the result of a join, etc. - *from another relation** would be the most general formulation), it is often easiest to do it with the `MERGE` statement. This is a perfect example.

> **Relation* is a fancy term for a table or anything that resembles
>   one, such as the result of a join, an aggregate operation, or really
>   any kind of `SELECT` statement.

```
merge into table_2 t2
  using
    ( select t1.id, s.spl_1
      from   table_1 t1 join table_2 s on t1.rel_id = s.id
    ) x
    on ( x.id = t2.id )
  when matched then update
    set t2.spl_2 = case when t2.spl_2 = x.spl_1 then null else t2.spl_2 end,
        t2.spl_3 = case when t2.spl_3 = x.spl_1 then null else t2.spl_3 end,
        t2.spl_4 = case when t2.spl_4 = x.spl_1 then null else t2.spl_4 end
    where x.spl_1 in (t2.spl_2, t2.spl_3, t2.spl_4)  
       -- WHERE clause so that you only update rows that need to be updated!
;

2 rows merged.

select * from table_2;

        ID      CATGY      SPL_1      SPL_2      SPL_3      SPL_4
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       123        180          6          0          0           
       456        181          7          0          0          0
       789        180          8                                0
       321        181          9          0          0          0
```